# Why does the script run fine in the script editor, but when saved as an application it does not function consistently

Tags: macos, applescript

So I made this script using script editor, and when I run it through the script editor it runs perfectly, opens the webpage, goes into full screen mode just fine. However when I save it as an application and then run it from the desktop it opens Firefox which is great, but then it does not go full screen on the first try, sometimes it takes the 2nd or 3rd or even 4th try of quitting Firefox then re-running the script for it to work.

The script is as follows

```
do shell script "open '/Applications/Firefox.app' http://website.net/"

delay 3

tell application "System Events"

    keystroke "f" using {command down, shift down}
end tell
```

Comment: Delay too short, causing race condition maybe? Have you tried tell-ing Firefox instead of System Events?

Comment: I have tried different delays, no difference between any, I will try telling Firefox instead and get back to you. @AlexanderO'Mara

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Still inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The do shell script approach:
1. doesn't have the script wait for the command to finish, and
2. doesn't bring firefox to the front, so your script app is still in the front when the rest of the script happens.

```
tell application "Firefox"
    activate
    open location "http://website.net/"
end tell
delay 3
tell application "System Events"
    delay 3
    keystroke "f" using {command down, shift down}
end tell
```

Comment: So I did this but it doesn't work if Firefox consistently. And it will never work if Firefox hasn't been opened before the script runs.

Comment: To help, be more specific. What's the problem?

Comment: So if Firefox has not been launched yet and I test my script it works fine, brings up Firefox, goes into full screen mode, but when I Run it as an application it will never go full screen the first try, it could take 2 or 3 tries. I'm trying to understand why as an application the script doesn't work.

Comment: What happens if you give the delay a crazy long value like 10 secs. Maybe try also a delay before the activate  the key combo is being sent before Firefox is ready. AppleScript applications are terrible for this kind of use.

Comment: The same thing happens if I give a value like 10 or 20, if you have any alternatives you know of I wouldn't mind trying something else, in our office we have these AppleScript apps running and some work fine some don't, seems terribly inconsistent.

Comment: I tried adding a delay after like you said, seems to be working fine, thanks a lot!

tell application "Firefox"

    activate

    open location "http://website.net/"

end tell

delay 3

tell application "System Events"

    delay 3
    keystroke "f" using {command down, shift down}
end tell